# Excel "Don't update links" not working. I specifically tell Excel not to update my links, and it does it anyway, giving me an the #VALUE! error

Tags: excel, hyperlink

I have a spreadsheet which uses the OFFSET function in several cells.

It refers to date in another spreadsheet.

When I open the file, I don't want Excel to update the links but instead keep the values. I click "Don't update", but it does it anyway giving me the VALUE! error.

Same thing happens on different computers. How do I stop this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you just paste the values in? When DO you want it to update? Can you give an example of the formulas that are updating?

Comment: I only want it to update when I'm working with both files.

But when I send it to someone else, I just want them to be able to see the values, and not receive the #VALUE! error.

Like I said, although I click on "Don't update" links, it still does it. Funnily enough, only the cells using the OFFSET function seem to be getting the error.

Comment: Can you post the formula that is using Offset?

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, `OFFSET` requires the workbook to be open. Many OFFSET formulas can be changed to an `INDEX` function that does not have the same restrictions

```
=OFFSET('C:\...\[Main Database.xlsx]Technical'!$S481, (ROW(B14) -1)*1,0)
```

would be re-written as

```
=INDEX('C:\...\[Main Database.xlsx]Technical'!$S:$S, (ROW(B14) -1)*1+481)
```

(path removed to avoid scroll bars when looking at solution)

The cell is changed to a column reference:  `$S481` -> `$S:$S`
The previous cell row is added to the index:  `(ROW(B14) -1)*1`  ->  `(ROW(B14) -1)*1 + 481`
Column not needed, as you have `0`

If you have a 3rd or 4th parameter to the offset function then index will not work, but you could add another sheet that has a simple `='C:\...\[Main Database.xlsx]Technical'!A1` (and all other cells needed to be referenced) and then reference that sheet with the offset, instead of the original workbook

Comment: Hi Sean, Thanks for your answer.

The formula seems to work fine. If I open the file and select "Don't Update", Excel does it anyway, giving me the VALUE! error on the cells using OFFSET, but the INDEX thing works.

My only problem though, is that when I pull down and drag the INDEX function, it leaves every second cell blank. This is a problem, because I would like it to ignore those blanks which are present in the column it is pulling data from. Is there any way around that?

Thanks once again for your kind help. Cheers!

Comment: Just to elaborate. I have the INDEX pulling data from a column which is like this S1 has data, S2 is blank, S3 has data, S4 is blank.
 
However, I would like the Index function to just put them one top of each other, without the blanks.

Comment: multiply the row by 2 - as the offset of 481 is not being updated (as it would with your OFFSET formula), the value you are adding on needs to be altered too